# How to enable edit mode when user taps static tableview cell?

Tags: ios, tableview, edit

In my basic app I currently store data in a table with no issue and when the user selects a row it loads the relevant data into a new VC with a static tableview (of three cells). Now, I'd like to be able to edit the values of these three cells when the user taps them (possibly during edit mode), much like in the Contacts app. How would I go about doing this? Also, is there a way to disable delete functionality while in edit mode?

Answer (score 2):

Call `setEditing:animated:` method for table view and implement required delegate methods such as

- `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`
- `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`
- `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`

I would suggest to read this chapter

[Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1)